# Importe QR image from gallery and scan it using zxing library 2.0

Tags: android, zxing

How to scan QR code images from the gallery. I am using Zxing library for scanning the QR code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android) to decode files.

Comment: I have used ur zxing lib in my appln. and want to do the same.